# PIC 18F46K22 SPI speed

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, pic, spi

I am using PIC 18F46K22 in SPI master mode to communicate with an ADC chip. The FOSC frequency is 64MHz(external 16MHz crystal with PLL on) so based on the PIC manual the maximum SPI speed should be FOSC/4 = 16MHz. But when I use SPI to send 8-bit data it takes around 1.6us to be sent. That means the SPI speed is only around 5MHz. My compiler is MicroC PRO for PIC and I have engaged SPI library functions for initializing and reading data via SPI. Can anyone help me with this issue please?

This is how I initialized SPI1:

```
SPI1_Init_Advanced(_SPI_MASTER_OSC_DIV4, _SPI_DATA_SAMPLE_END, _SPI_CLK_IDLE_HIGH, _SPI_HIGH_2_LOW);
```

and these are the code lines to read data via SPI:

```
Take1 = SPI1_Read(0);  // MSB of ADC shift register
Take2 = SPI1_Read(0);
Take3 = SPI1_Read(0);  // LSB of ADC shift register
```

I used external crystal(HS oscillator). I did the corresponding settings in "Edit Project" section of the MikroC PRO sotfware(Oscillator Selection:HS oscillator(high power>16 MHz), 4X PLL Enable: Enabled).

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you could post the code that you are using to initialize and read the data from the SPI (even if you are just calling functions from a library). It is hard to troubleshoot a problem when we cannot see what you have done. It would also be useful to see how you are initializing your oscillators.

Comment: What value of load capacitors do you have on the crystal? How are you measuring the 1.6us interval? Have you tried using the internal 16MHz HFINTOSC with PLL instead of your external crystal?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you this solution :

Initialise your PIC with 16MHz internal oscillator, and enable 4X PLL in MikroC Editor.
Then, set the pin RA6 as CLOCKOUT, which will output your system frequency / 4.
That means, if your 64MHz is well initialized, you will get a 16MHz square wave on RA6.

```
OSCCON = 0b01110010; //Enable 16MHz internal oscillator, running from INTOSC
OSCTUNE.PLLEN = 1;   //Enable PLL operation, 4x clock set from HFINTOSC
```

Try reading the status of this bit :

```
OSCCON2.PLLRDY
```

If it's set (1), then your clock is coming from the PLL. Otherwise, it's not properly enabled.